# How to Multiple Selection image getid(like:MediaStore.Image.thoumble._ID)

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to work with image structure and i want to know how to get image id when i select multiple image(i use contextual action mode ) 
please give me answer my problem ........

public class GalleryImages extends Activity {

```
GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;
protected Object mActionMode;
private int columnIndex;
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
 String Tag ="sample";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galleryimages);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lvImagesGallery);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);



    gridView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mode=null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.add_Tag:
                int nr = 0;
                //imageAdapter.clearSelection();
                mode.finish();
        }
        return false;
        }

    };

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            ActionMode mode =startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
             mode.setTitle(gridView.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected");
             gridView.setSelected(true);


        }
    });
    /*listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
             startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
             listView.setSelected(true);
             return true;
        }
    });*/
}



class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater layout;
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        layout = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layout.inflate(R.layout.gridimage, null);

        }
        picturesView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivGalleryImage);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                        + imageID));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change `gridView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` to

```
gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

Grid view can return the image's id and position with respect to the grid view and not with respect to your xml.

To get the id of the image in the grid view

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id and position = "+id+" "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```